# find image pixels in python using Terminal?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

Consider I have an image `image.png` in a folder `XYZ`. I need a Python script which asks the user to enter the image name and the output should be the image pixel and size.

I tried on terminal using `sips` command as following:

```
sips -g pixelWidth -g pixelHeight image.png
```

I need to incorporate the same on Python.  I tried with this code

```
import os
for rootpath,dir,file in os.walk("/Volumes/Macintosh HD/users/username/myfolder"):
    for files in file:      
        def test(name):
            return (os.system(sips -g pixelWidth -g pixelHeight name))
```

But this is not helpful. I am new to Python and doing some experiments. So any help/idea will be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to read a Python Tutorial, specifically, read about data types, functions, arguments. You can find a list with plenty of tutorials in http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers

Answer (score 1):

Your logic should be:

1. Check to see if the image file exists, if it doesn't, exit with appropriate message.
2. Call your function with the image's *full path*
3. Display the results back to the user.

Here's how to do that:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def run_command(user_input):
    image_path = '/home/user/images/'
    command_to_run = '/usr/bin/sips'

    if not user_input:
        return "You didn't enter anything!"

    if not os.path.exists(image_page+user_input):
        return "I cannot find that image!"
    else:
        output = Popen([command_to_run,
                        "-g", "PixelWidth",
                        "-g", "PixelHeight",
                        image_path+user_input], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
        return "The result is: ",output

 user_input = raw_input("Please enter the image name: ")
 print run_command(user_input)
```